# Copy id element to others elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link that has an id from a database. When I click on it how can i copy this id to  2 buttons by applying to them the same id ? Behold how i try :

```
1- <a  class="godown" id="<?=$row->id_apoint;?>"><?=$row->nombre;?></a>
2- <button  class="bill" >button1</button>  <button  class="bill" >button2</button>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.godown').click(function() {
var godown = $(this).attr('id');
// How can I copy the variable **godown ** to the buttons so that they have the save id as godown ?
});
```

Thanks

Comment: *"...how can i copy this id to 2 buttons by applying to them the same id"* You don't. Having more than one element with the same ID is invalid. This sounds like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); why do you think you want to do that?

Comment: You **should not** repeat ids.  They are meant to be unique by web standards.  So how do you do this?  The answer is **don't**.  https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-id

Comment: thanks you so much your are right

Comment: **var newItem = $("selector").clone();**  this will make a copy of selected tag. Also you can set value an attribute like this; **$(element).attr("attrName","newValue");**

Comment: In reality the 2 buttons are hidden, after I click on the link the are appeared. After I click on one of them I need this id to process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: You need a class, you should never repeat ids.  Classes are intended to be repeated as a method of grouping elements.  And you already have a class on them.

Comment: Ok i am going to use class. How can I assign the class of the link to the class of the 2 buttons ?